# How to extract time from a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, time

The problem is the time displays in different forms,like

```
19:03 
3:29 pm
3:29 PM
```

How to handle this? thanks

Comment: Don't use a regex, use a date/time parser.

Comment: be clearer. are you trying to find time strings within other content, or just parse the time from individual inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you write a regex for each possible time format and `OR` them together, you can't simply do with regex.

What I mean is starting from

```
(rgx1|rgx2|rgx3)
```

where rgxX is a valid time regex. In your example you can try

```
([\d]{1,2}:[\d]{1,2}|[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{1,2} [aApP][mM])
```

But this regex will also match `45:89 PM` which is not a valid time

If you need to *extract* a time then these are useful, while if you need to *verify* you can't with regex

Comment: Thank you,I got those string from webpages I got,so I don't needs to verify.How to `extract` from a string like `March 30, 2003 02:40 rounds`(what I expected is `2:40`)?

Comment: I used the above express ion but it shows error                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using something like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this problem.

What you could do is define your set of dateformats, then parse them in a loop until one format succeeds (i.e. doesn't throw an exception). Something along the lines of the following snippet:

```
for(SimpleDateFormat fmt : formats) {
    try { 
        return fmt.parse(date, startpos);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Naturally this assumes that you created a list of different format patterns. Generally, [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is also a good complement to java time.

Comment: Which is basically what [`DateUtils.parseDate()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) does

Comment: Excellent addition, `apache-commons` tend to show up to the rescue every now and then.

Comment: Thank you,but there is something else in the string.I have to use regex to extract and parse like yours.Your answer is still useful,one up-vote :)

Comment: @Shisoft, there's no good generic way to do that without knowing what input you have. In your above example for instance it would suffice to split on newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Joda's [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). It's guaranteed to be threadsafe, unlike SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

[`DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, patterns[])`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) from [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) lets you specify multiple templates that will be tried in turn. Perhaps that's an option if you can identify all possible data formats that will occur.